Karate dry runner
I have created a dry runner for karate feature files as shown below:
public class DryRunner {
   @Test
   void testParallel() throws IOException {
      Runner.builder().dryRun(true);
   }
}

No HTML report is getting generated in the target folder. What I might be missing?

Call parallel(1) to complete the "builder" and run tests. Something like this:
Runner.path("classpath:").dryRun(true).parallel(1);


i have a question.. where dry runner for karate can be used because in karate there is no step definition?

@user13245465 refer docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#dry-run
